# Application windows go behind the dock (gnome)

Tags: gnome, dock, taskbar

If move applications near the dock, they will go behind the dock rather than in front. How can I fix this?

[image: Windows go behind the dock]

Comment: Applications will not hover over the dock, as that will prevent you from using the feature. One option you might consider is to "auto-hide" the dock when an application window is in that part of the screen. This will allow you to use more of the screen while still having the dock when you move the mouse all the way to the left.

Comment: i enable auto hide and auto hide on full screen. but , it not works